# dd_resccue attempt yields empty .img file

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a hard drive with a some data corruption and am attempting to recover the data with dd_rescue. I am running Ubuntu 10 running off a thumb drive drive (my primary boot disk is running Windows 7). I cant remember exactly what the command was (see explanation below) but it was something like:

```
dd_rescue media/MyBadDisk media/MyGoodDisk
```

The task took about 4 days to run on a 500 GB HDD and I wasn't around when it actually finished. The terminal window was blank and was not showing a prompt anymore. There was a cursor and keystrokes would advance the cursor but nothing would actually display. On the destination disk there is a new MyBadDisk.img file but it is 0 bytes.

Did I do something wrong? I want to run the task again but I dont want to wait another 4 days to find out I screwed something up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like it finished, but try Scrounge NTFS.  I've had good luck with it when dd_rescue wouldn't do the trick.

Comment: Is 4+ days really a reasonable amount of time for dd_rescue to run on a 500 GB drive?